# Openshift application shows blank page

Tags: mysql, web-applications, openshift

I have an Tomcat7 application on Openshift. I have also added a MySQL cartridge and phpMyAdmin cartridge. The .WAR file is deployed correctly, the server starts but in my URL I get a blank page. I have done all the necessary steps.Here's a copy of the logs:

```
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
        ... 20 more
    WARN  BasicResourcePool - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1931e06 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
    WARN  BasicResourcePool - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1931e06 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
    WARN  BasicResourcePool - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1931e06 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
    WARN  JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    INFO  Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
   INFO  LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
   INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
   INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
   INFO  UpdateTimestampsCache - HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
INFO  StandardQueryCache - HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.security.Identity]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.parameter.Parameter]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.scheme.RenderElement]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.query.OrderBy]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.security.RoleMembers]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.query.Query]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.tjoblet.orm.DocumentType]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.security.AuthorizationPolicy]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.scheme.RenderScheme]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.query.Criterion]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.PanelDefinition]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.scheme.RenderScheme.elements]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.query.Query.criteria]; using defaults.
WARN  AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.web4thejob.orm.query.Query.orderings]; using defaults.
INFO  HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1bqop6w9d1uh6f8z1y57nu9|1124745, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1bqop6w9d1uh6f8z1y57nu9|1124745, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
WARN  BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@10116ec -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2393)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:183)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:172)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:188)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1798)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:636)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
        ... 20 more
WARN  BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1b7f01 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2393)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:183)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:172)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:188)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1798)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:636)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
        ... 20 more
WARN  BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@d69f0d -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2393)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:183)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:172)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:188)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1798)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:636)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
        ... 20 more
WARN  BasicResourcePool - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1931e06 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
WARN  BasicResourcePool - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1931e06 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
WARN  BasicResourcePool - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1931e06 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:517)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.findUniqueByQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.web4thejob.security.SpringSecurityService.getAdministratorIdentity(SpringSecurityService.java:65)
        at org.web4thejob.orm.MappingInitializer.ensureAdministratorExists(MappingInitializer.java:72)
        at org.web4thejob.orm.MappingInitializer.onApplicationEvent(MappingInitializer.java:49)
        at org.web4thejob.orm.MappingInitializer.onApplicationEvent(MappingInitializer.java:40)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:776)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
        at org.web4thejob.context.ContextUtil.refresh(ContextUtil.java:318)
        at org.web4thejob.context.ORMLauncher.onApplicationEvent(ORMLauncher.java:39)
        at org.web4thejob.context.ORMLauncher.onApplicationEvent(ORMLauncher.java:31)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:776)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:446)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:431)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:677)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1406)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:594)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:514)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:743)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:670)
        ... 45 more
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:37 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.WebManager <init>
INFO: Starting ZK 7.0.0 CE (build: 2013112611)
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:37 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser parseConfigXml
INFO: Loading system default
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:37 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser parse
INFO: Parsing jar:file:/var/lib/openshift/567a72f30c1e660388000150/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/twebapp/WEB-INF/lib/zul-7.0.0.jar!/metainfo/zk/zk.xml
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:37 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ConfigParser parse
INFO: Parsing jndi:/localhost/twebapp/WEB-INF/zk.xml
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/twebapp] startup failed due to previous errors
INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 29 16:13:14 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  EhCacheManagerFactoryBean - Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/twebapp] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/twebapp] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/twebapp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap@ab4d80]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/567a72f30c1e660388000150/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/twebapp.war has finished in 114,969 ms
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.4.1-8080"]
Dec 29, 2015 4:14:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 115412 ms
```

Comment: Can you please give information on how you are making a connection from Tomcat to MySQL - Are you using the env variables?

Comment: No I am not. You're right, that's what I was missing. Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

This free book
https://www.openshift.com/promotions/ebook.html

and then go to the chapter on connecting a DB to your application.  There are several ways to get them though. I usually SSH into the gear and then at the prompt type

```
env |grep -i mysql
```

and you should see the environment variable to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks like the environment variables are as they should be.   Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, sometimes when I use the rhc tail command, the logs stop at mysql.